# Getting value of var by its name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying get value of var by its name:

```
var1='Hello'

var2 = getTextFromFirstTextBox() //text in label is "var1"

var3 = ${var2}
```

Everything works, but here I should get 'hello' but it doesn't work

```
var4 = ${var3}
```

What I must to do to set value of value1 to value4?

Comment: @Sarfraz: FTFY, "... this *misfeature* is known as ...".

Comment: Whenever I see a question like this, I taste a little bit of vomit in my mouth. At least there is room for improving (and a number of answers with that thought in mind) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take this one line from your question:

```
var1='Hello'
```

As it stands, that will create a global variable (regardless of where the code is). Global variables are properties of the global object, which is `window` on browsers, so you can access that via bracketed notation with a string (e.g., `window["var1"]`) as a couple of the answers here mention. But that's only part of the story.

If the code is at global scope, it's fairly obvious you're creating a global variable. If that line appears as-is in a *function*, it still creates a global variable — you're falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

The moral of the story is: Use `var` when creating variables:

```
var var1 = 'Hello';
```

Now you're explicitly creating a variable in the *current* scope — e.g., at global scope if that's where the code is, or at function scope if that's where the code is.

So global variables are properties of `window`; how 'bout function variables, are they properties of an object? Yes, they are (it's called the "variable object" in the spec, and it's a very real thing, not a spec abstraction), but you have no means of accessing that object directly, there's no symbol or name you can use to get at it. If you want to get a function's variable using a string version of its name, your only option is `eval`, and don't do that. Instead, refactor the code and make the thing you need to access the property of an object:

```
var thingsToLookUp = {
    var1: "Hello",
    var2: "There"
};
alert(thingsToLookUp["var1"]); // alerts "Hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var1 = 'Hello'
var2 = getTextFromFirstTextBox() //text in label is "var1"
```

Now, `var2 = "var1"`. If you want the *value* of `var1` assigned to `var3` you can:

```
var3 = window[var2];
```

---

**EDIT**
See @jleedev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602033/getting-value-of-var-by-its-name/4602073#4602073) for the scope issue raised in the comments.

Comment: Nice(+1), but that only works for global (window-scoped) variables.

Comment: Of course this assumes that `var1` is global (which it shouldn't be).

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd @delnan Yes, I didn't think of the scope :-S

Answer (score 4):

You can access global variables as properties of `window`:

```
> var1='Hello'
"Hello"
> var2='var1'
"var1"
> window[var2]
"Hello"
```

This is similar to Python, by the way — based on your question it looks like you’re expecting something like PHP’s variable variables.

It’s *much* better to explicitly create an object for storing what you need:

```
> dict = {} // Create a new Object
Object
> dict['var1'] = 'Hello' // Index it with a string
"Hello"
> dict.var1 // Or directly if you know the name you want
"Hello"
```

Comment: You've got a big misunderstanding or misrepresentation of `this` in there. It *happens* that `this` is `window` at global scope, but you wouldn't want to rely on it for the above.

Comment: +1 for the latter. I am shocked every time questions like this one come up and people suggest `eval` (or - not nearly as bad but still a bad idea - mixing your variables with a mapping of user input) instead of highlighting the real solution - a dictionary that is seperate from the namespace your code lives in.

Comment: @TJ The question contains no context, so it’s hard to tell if global variables are desired or not. I have tried to clarify the difference between properties and variables.

Comment: @jleedev: I'm just saying, it doesn't matter. Talk about `window`, of course, but if you bring `this` into it, you're just confusing matters. Other than when `this` = `window`, `var` s (explicit or implicit) never become properties of `this`.

Comment: Further: *"If it was defined globally or as some object’s property"* It clearly *isn't* the latter, because it's a free symbol (no `obj.` in front of it). I think we can safely assume the OP isn't using `with`, which is the only way (other than a global variable) that it would be the property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Variables are properties of their parent object,</del> Global variables can be handled as properties of the `window` object so you can do something like this:

```
var var1, var2, var3;
function getTextFromFirstTextBox(){
    return "var1";
}
var1 = 'Hello';
var2 = getTextFromFirstTextBox();
var3 = window[var2];
alert(var3); // Shows: Hello
```

Comment: Variables are not defined as properties of their parent object/scope. The top-level scope is just special. `function () { var x = ...; /* no way to access x dynamically here without eval */ }`

Comment: *"Variables are properties of their parent object"* No they aren't. It happens that `window` is the "variable object" (to use the spec's term) for the global scope, but that's the only place you have direct access to the variable object. Within a function, you can't get at it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, if only for the comments it triggered (thanks to @pst and @T.J.), as they teached me a bit more about JS internals.

Comment: You are right, I terribly misworded my answer. I'll think about a more accurate text.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder hey, I was here first ;-)

Comment: @pst: ;-) Guess I'd been reading the page for a moment before seeing it.